# How do I add a path in my bash profile for anaconda installed on another drive?

Tags: bash, macos, anaconda

I have two drives installed in my computer, one running the OS and one the home directory. I have used anaconda and python on the home directory, but since the drive running the OS is an SSD, I would like to run anaconda and all python programming on this drive.

I have uninstalled anaconda from the old drive and deleted the path variables in the bash profile.

After reinstalling anaconda now on the new drive I've tried to add the path in my bash profile to the anaconda3/bin file, however I get the following errors:

```
-bash: /Volumes/HDD/.bash_profile: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-bash: /Volumes/HDD/.bash_profile: line 26: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I have attached my bash profile to the question. I have deleted a fair bit of stuff when I uninstalled anaconda from the previous drive, but it was only things referring to itself - could it be that I deleted some other path variable?

I might have some fundamental problem with this split that I don't know about - a question I have also been searching was how I can change terminal to also 'work' on the mother directory `/Volumes/`.

My directories:

```
/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3  # containing anaconda
/Volumes/SSHD    # containing the home directory, 'running' terminal
```

I have tried to write

```
export PATH="/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

into the bash profile, but the same errors came up, so I copied the standard conda init from another question but still no luck.

````
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false ‘/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ]; then
        . "/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<```

export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "

export CLICOLOR=1

export LSCOLORS=AhFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BASH is complaining that it found a start of a quote, but couldn't find the end.

Line 3 of your script:

```
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false ‘/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
```

Should be:

```
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
```

Note the subtle difference between the original character: ‘ and the replaced character ' after false and before /Volumes

You also have an unterminated quote on line 7 after "conda.sh". Should be:

```
    if [ -f "/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
```

Comment: thank you so much! I have been reading about the quotation mark problems but didn't realise it was the problem.

So would what is the issue with `export PATH="/Volumes/SSD/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" ` ? Do I have to use a single ' twice, or the double " ?

Comment: When trying to get a variable to expand, use double-quote ("") and when trying NOT to have a variable expand, use single quotes (''). Example: foo=bar; echo "$foo" will return 'bar'. echo '$foo' will return '$foo'. 

To answer your question, remove the \ at the beginning of the line. It escapes the "e" of "export" meaning the shell will try to run "xport" which as a command, doesn't exist by default.